# JSON.net - deserialize varying objects into one object

Tags: c#, json, wpf, serialization, json.net

Sorry for the messy title, I'm not sure how I should explain it better.
The JSON string I have:

```
{
"Name that varies here": {
    "id": 01,
    "ArrayOfType": [{
        "name": "a name",
        "id": 01
    },

    {
        "name": "a name",
        "id": 02
    }]
},
"Another name": {
        "id": 02,
        "ArrayOfSameType": [{
            "name": "a name",
            "id": 03
        },
....
```

I dont know how I should deserialize it, especially because the Object-name varies. Basically what I'd want is a List where someObject has String name, int ID and a List.

How should I create the object and deserialize it? So far I have only deserialized arrays/objects that are all called the same. I could make a class for each name (Name that varies here.cs, Another name.cs) with the variables and then deserialize it into that class.

Comment: Deserailize that into a `Dictionary<string, TheValueType>`

Comment: That worked out perfectly, thank you very much!